# Custom align specific part of tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have a tabularx environment with 3 columns and 5 rows. How can I align first row and first column right to left, while the rest of the table are aligned left to right?
P.S. that currently my tabularx is defined as:

`\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X}`

Thanks
align left in a word processor application!:
[image: Align Left]

Comment: What does ‘aligned left to right’ (or ‘right to left’) mean?

Comment: @Bernard: Text orientation, perhaps, like in Arabic or Farsi language? Only a guess

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: you're probably right.

Comment: yes, I exactly mean text orientation

Comment: Maybe see the `bidi` package (to be used with `xelatex`).

Comment: suppose I am using English everywhere... this should be possible in latex tabularx, Right? I mean there is no need to use bidi, assume I have words in first row and column which I need them to be aligned right to left, and numbers in  every other cell which I need them to be aligned left to right

Comment: To change alignment for one cell only, use \multicolumn{1}{r}{...}  Note: you may have to add a | inside the \multicolumn.

Comment: @JohnKormylo could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, one example of using `\multicolumn` to change cell formatting.

Note that if the X field gets shorter the the "Will fit." entry, it will waste space to the right of the paragraph.  If you make the "Must fit." entry too long, it will go beyond the edge of the tabular and (interestingly) the X fields will shrink.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{6cm}{|r|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|X|}{All X fields are the same width.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Must fit.}\\
\hline
Will fit. & All X fields are the same width.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx with \multicolumn]

Comment: thanks, but I have to use tabularx otherwise my table wont fit in pagewidth.. What would change if those |r|r| were replaced be X?

Comment: You can intermix X fields with tabular fields using \multicolumn just fine.  You can run tabularx without any X fields, but the last column may wind up too narrow or too wide.